# Executing PHP with HTML Button (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i got a website with some buttons and a camerastream which shows a coffee machine. with php function i'm able to set the machine on/off via TCP/IP messages. Now i would like to send on/off commands over button, without refreshing the website. After reading some similar threads, i recognized that the only way is using AJAX.

After pressing Button the Page doesnt refresh but it seems that something in backround get done. But my "Test" String doesnt get show.

Does anyone know whats wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance!

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    echo 'TEST';
}
?>
```

**buttonClick.js**

```
function myAjax() {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'ajax.php',
       data:{action:'call_this'},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }

  });
}
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="buttonClick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
....
....
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SET ON" onClick="myAjax()">
</form>
....
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Echo` or `print` is correct, The comment above is wrong, adding my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified Mouad Nejjari code as below and this works

**index.php**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btnTest">Click</button>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnTest').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'ajax.php',
       data:{action:'call_this'},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }
     });
    })});    
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    echo 'TEST';
}
?>
```

Comment: after changing <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> to <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script> it worked. i dont get it, because my jquery file is in same folder like all other files. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped.
Having latest jquery might resolve your issue too (to have it local). Also, check the console to see if there is any error (with your old code) to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the HTML element `input` with a type set to `submit`, this means that on click the page assumes you want to be redirected to the handling page URL normally supplied in the Form tag. You can use the javascript method of [PreventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) or you can change the element from a form submit to a link like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="buttonClick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
....
....
<a href="javascript: myAjax()">SET ON</a>
....
....
</body>
</html>
```

A link with a javascript href will not try and redirect. Your example left the page before waiting for the php script to return.

Comment: tried to use your example, still doesnt work. at first i supposed the blank in href was guilty, but it wasnt. Guess i have to take a look on the PreventDefault() function

Answer (score 0):

Try This, ajax.php :

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    echo 'TEST';
}
?>
```

buttonClick.js :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#form1").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'ajax.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
            }
         });
    })
})
```

index.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="buttonClick.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
....
....
<form id="form1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SET ON">
</form>
....
....
</body>
</html>
```